Showing that an affine map in the plane has a fixed point
I recently came across the following question:

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2  \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by: $$f(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{3}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\
y\\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 10\\
-4\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Show that f has a unique fixed point p and  $\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} f^n(z) = p$ for every z.

My idea is show that $f$ is a contraction and apply the Banach theorem for fixed points. I tried two approaches:

Show that $f$ has a limited derivative $D_f(a)$ in every point $a$, but how could you calculate the norm of  $$\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2} & \dfrac{1}{3} \\
\dfrac{2}{3} & \dfrac{3}{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}?$$

Show that $$\bigg\lvert \dfrac{D_f(a)v - D_f(a)w}{\lvert v - w \rvert}\bigg\lvert  \ = \ \bigg\lvert \dfrac{D_f(a)[v - w]}{\lvert v - w \rvert}\bigg\lvert \leq \sup_{\lvert z \rvert = 1} \lvert D_f(a)z\rvert ,$$ but I was unsuccessful.


Can you give me suggestions?

You don't need a sledghammer for this problem. You just need to tap it with your fingernail. Write out the formulas for the coordinate functions $f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$. Then solve the system of equations $x=f_1(x,y)$, $y=f_2(x,y)$.

You want to prove that there exists an unique $x$ such that $Ax+b=x$ for the appropriate matrix $A$ and vector $b$. This is equivalent to showing that the linear system $(A-I)x=-b$ has an unique solution, which in turn is equivalent to showing that $A-I$  is invertible.

@Albert: You also have to show that $\lim_{n \longrightarrow \infty} f^n(x) = p$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^2$.

I apologize for the later edit. I only noticed that a part was missing when I posted the question.

Compute $\lVert Df(x) \rVert_{\infty}$ for every $x$. You will see that this is smaller than one. Then Banach's fixed point theorem immediately gives you everything you want.

BTW, you shouldn't use $x$ in two different ways like this (as the $x$-coordinate of a vector, and as the vector itself).

@HyperbolicPDEfriend $|Df|_{\infty}$ is not smaller than one... Nor any other norm (induced by a vector norm).

Sorry, you are right, I confused something

Showing that $f$ has a unique fixed point does not require the use of the fixed point theorem, you just need to show that the linear system $(x,y) = f(x,y)$ has a unique solution, which is easy to accomplish.
Regarding the convergence of the fixed point iterations, the situation is a bit more complicated because the spectral norm of the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is larger than one. This means that $f$ will not be a contraction under any norm. In fact, the iteration will not converge for all initial approximations, try for intance with $z=(1,1)$ and you'll see the the sequence is not converging to the fixed point.
